# how to have a body background image behind a single form?

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>EasyP Home Page </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="\Model\styles.css">
</head>

<body>

<form name="input" action="demo_form_action.asp" method="get">
Search: <input type="text" name="key_search">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    style>

body, html {
    background-image: url("blue-nature-red-white-balloons-hd-wallpapers.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 1400px 1400px;
}

form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    line-height: 700px;
}

</style>
```

When I open the webpage locally on my machine using the latest version of google chrome, the background and all the styles for body are ignored. However, the form appears and is formatted correctly. How do I keep the style of the form and the body? I want to set it up this way because I will add additional elements to my html page such as a logo, and links (im stuck at this part though)

Comment: Vaibhav S. solution works :) http://jsfiddle.net/4xnfubfe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the CSS rule is incorrectly formatted it will be ignored.

```
<style>
body, html {
    background-image: url("http://whitedove-coding.com/static/whitedove-829.png");
        background-position: center;
    background-size: 1400px 1400px;
}

form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    line-height: 700px;
}
```

As a external CSS the first rule is incorrectly formatted - remove the html tag from the external CSS and the first rule is correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

> body {
>
> > background: url('blue-nature-red-white-balloons-hd-wallpapers.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
> >
> > -webkit-background-size: cover;
> >
> > -moz-background-size: cover;
> >
> > -o-background-size: cover;
> >
> > background-size: cover;
>
> }

Change CSS for your form tag.

> > .form-signin {
> >
> > > max-width: 330px;
> > >
> > > padding: 15px;
> > >
> > > margin: 0 auto;
> >
> > }

HTML for "form" tag.

> > `<form class="form-signin" action="demo_form_action.asp" method="get">`

Comment: did not work. i changed the url for my image and it still did not work. if i change the order of the style sheet and put the form{} before body{}, the background appears, but the form isnt formatted

Comment: (http://jsfiddle.net/4xnfubfe/8/) Kindly check the link. I've edit little bit on the Jatin's Link.

Comment: try changing the background of body{} to a color like blue. It will not work. The same happening with me, but with an image instead.

Comment: i do not want to change the style of the form. the current style allows the form to be centered vertically and horizontally. your solution only makes the form centered horizontally. I know the name of your class doesn't matter, but it's not a "sign-in" form either. I am using the form to do a search in my database.